# Map reduce- Split and write in HDFS by day/hour/minutes

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have input file like below

**Input file**

```
**Regid   Epoch Timestamp**  
f77xvP  1509073785106 
2YXsF7r 1509073795109
GUf98M1 1509073805109 
JNFXto1 1509073815110
```

This is what i have to do, Read the above input file from HDFS and write in HDFS with separate file by partitioning by date /time / hour / minutes.

I did Research on this Can be done in using Hive but is it possible to do using partitioning / Reducer.Can you please help me in what way we can achieve this

```
package com.main;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.Properties;

    import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
    import org.json.JSONObject;



    public class JsonMain {

        public static Properties props;

        public static class Mapperclass extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>{
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            public void map(LongWritable mkey, Text mvalue, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
                try{
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(mvalue.toString());
                    String regId = (String)obj.get("regId");
                    String time = (String)obj.get("time");
                    Date date = new Date(Long.parseLong(time));         
    //              long epoch = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //              System.out.println(epoch);
    //              Date date = new Date(epoch);
                    String datestring = dateFormat.format(date); 
                    context.write(new Text(regId), new Text(time + " " + datestring ));
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }



        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //  props = new Properties();
            //FileInputStream propFile = new FileInputStream(args[0].trim());
            //props.load(propFile);

            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Map Reduce");

            job.setJarByClass(JsonMain.class);
            job.setMapperClass(Mapperclass.class);      
            job.setNumReduceTasks(0);

            job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

            job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);


            job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
            job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);



            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

            System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
        }

    }
```

The above code write in HDFS as below.

```
Ef77xvP 1509073785106 2017-10-26 20:09:45
2YXsF7r 1509073795109 2017-10-26 20:09:55
GUf98M1 1509073805109 2017-10-26 20:10:05
JNFXto1 1509073815110 2017-10-26 20:10:15
bkFbEK3 1509073825110 2017-10-26 20:10:25
LDze9od 1509073835110 2017-10-26 20:10:35
y0Zs8gF 1509073845111 2017-10-26 20:10:45
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use Hive, Pig, or Spark?

Comment: @cricket_007: i agree that we can do with Hive, PIG, SPARK, But in my requirement they asked me to do in MR Job.Am not sure we can achieve this in MR. Can you help me on this?